# el gradient de mi fondo e imagen cambian cuando despliego el teclado

Tags: flutter, imagen, dart, teclado, gradient

alguien me puede ayudar, estoy haciendo un Login de practica en donde coloque un radient y una imagen PNG, y cuando despliego el teclado para llenar el formulario el gradient sube al margen del teclado y la Imagen PNG acorta su tamaño, no se si hay alguna propiedad que me permita dejarlo estatico, garcias por su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Te estaría faltando que agregues el código de como esta hecho tu componente.

Comment: Podrías colocar el código de esa vista? para poder darte una respuesta mas detallada

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisar [ask],saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es encerrar el `body` de tu `scaffold` en un `SingleChildScrollView`, luego de esto como hijo le asignarías un `Stack`, en este `stack` pondrías primero la imagen con la propiedad `fit: BoxFit.cover`, y luego de la imagen pondrías el resto del código donde tienes el formulario:

```
Scaffold(
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Stack(
       children: [
    //Aquí reemplazas con el widget donde tienes el gradient       
    // y la imagen
     Image.asset('assets/fondo.jpeg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
     //resto del código del formulario
    ],
   ),
  );
```